# What is the difference between @aws-sdk/client-ses and @aws-sdk/client-sesv2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-js

AWS's SDK for JavaScript version 3 seems to have 2 different clients for Simple Email Service (SES).

I realized I have been using @aws-sdk/client-sesv2 but:

- The actual doc on their GitHub repos is really hard to understand (see [v1](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/clients/client-ses) and [v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/clients/client-sesv2))
- Nowhere in the Github example do they show an example of sending an email or why there are 2 versions
- I found this [more useful documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com//en_us/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/ses-examples-sending-email.html) but they don't even mention v2?

Are we supposed to use v1 or v2? What are the differences between both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After poking around, the AWS SDK for JavaScript seems to have two versions:

- Version 2 under `@aws-sdk`:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk
- Version 3 under `@aws-sdk/client-*`: e.g., https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-ses

Version 2 of the SDK is meant to be entering maintenance mode in 2023.

Now that this first layer of confusion is cleared out, the AWS SES API also has 2 versions:

- SES API v1: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ses/index.html
- SES API v2: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ses/index.html

So based on this investigation, I presume that the packages points to the different API versions.

Comment: Did you ever find out what is going on here? I also noticed that the SES API has two versions, but I cannot find out why... I posted a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75416474/which-aws-simple-email-service-api-is-the-latest

Comment: I just replied back on your question. Version 2 would be the one I would implement to avoid upgrading later.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the name, v2 is actually the *older* version of the client.

You should use `@aws-sdk/client-ses`, which is v3.

**Source:**

See [the code examples section in AWS SES docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/example_ses_SendEmail_section.html), click the "Javascript" tab, the code example is headed:

> SDK for JavaScript (v3)

With the code snippet starting:

```
import { SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
```