# AWS-sdk/client-ses InvalidParameterValue: Message length is more than 10485760 bytes long: '20286031'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

When trying to test a payload in postman locally I get the following error:

```
2023-11-30 13:50:04.482 [error] - [ReqId : 77b1409d-4174-4974-a22a-8f1f1c00a981] : InvalidParameterValue: Message length is more than 10485760 bytes l
    at throwDefaultError (/mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:8:22)
    at /mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:18:39
    at de_SendRawEmailCommandError (/mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-ses/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_query.js:2418:20)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at /mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24
    at /mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/awsAuthMiddleware.js:14:20
    at /mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46
    at /mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:7:26 {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': [Object],
  Type: 'Sender',
  Code: 'InvalidParameterValue'
} (in message_controller.ts:58)
Call Stack:
    at DSLogger.error (/mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/src/shared/utils/log/logger.ts:101:15)
    at DSLogService.error (/mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/src/shared/services/log/log.service.ts:91:18)
    at MessageController.sendEmail (/mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/src/shared/controllers/message_controller.ts:58:20)
```

I found this post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74736041/what-is-the-difference-between-aws-sdk-client-ses-and-aws-sdk-client-sesv2) and tried to use `aws-sdk/client-sesv2`

But that led me to getting this error:

> TypeError: ses.sendRawEmail is not a function at
> /mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/ses-transport/index.js:267:43
> at
> /mnt/d/Repos/document-engine/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/ses-transport/index.js:251:43
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> [ERROR] 17:54:43 TypeError: ses.sendRawEmail is not a function

I then tracked down that error [here](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1254) on the nodemailer issues page in their github repo.
But it appears that should be fixed as it was addressed and closed.

So shouldn't this below with `v2` work?

```
import { Transporter, createTransport } from 'nodemailer';
import { Attachment } from 'nodemailer/lib/mailer';
import { MailOptions } from 'nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport';

import { SESv2, SESv2ClientConfig, SendEmailCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-sesv2';
// import { SES, SESClientConfig, SendRawEmailCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-ses';
import { BadRequestException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EmailContents } from '@shared/models/mail/mail.content';
import { DSEmailResponseModel } from '@shared/models/response/email_response.model';
import { DSAWSConfig } from '@shared/utils/aws/aws.config';

/**
 * Utility class to for configuring Node mailer.
 *
 * This class uses Amazon SES to send email.
 *
 * Note : Do not use this class directly instead use IQEmailService class.
 *
 * @export
 * @class DSMailer
 */
@Injectable()
export class DSMailer extends DSAWSConfig {
    private transporter: Transporter;

    /**
     * Function to configure Node mailer.
     *
     * This function throws system error which should be handled by the caller.
     *
     * @memberof DSMailer
     */
    configEmail(options: SESv2ClientConfig): void {
        const ses: any = new SESv2(options);
        this.transporter = createTransport({
            SES: { ses, aws: { SendEmailCommand } }
        });

        this.logService.info('Mailer configured successfully.');
    }
    ...more code...

}
```

Can anyone provide insight what I should be doing?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have got the same error, trying to send multiple payloads in a loop,  sqs crash with even 11731 bytes.